# Write Generic Test Cases in Behavior Driven Development

Tags: tdd, bdd

Can we  write generic test cases in BDD?
I mean that we have a generic test class, and we could have an instantiator to instantiate the value that we want and then execute the test?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: for example write a generic test case for security system,to support 2 different security model, 4-digit password and 8-digit password. I mean that I write one generic test case for both model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDD has a strong focus on customer communication, so I would recommend **not** to write generic test cases, as it will likely be harder for a customer to understand.  For example, I would prefer:

```
authenticates_user_with_4_digit_password
authenticates_user_with_8_digit_password
```

However, you should do what works best for your situation and if your customer understands a generic test case, then you should use it.

Comment: thank you! your answer clarify my opinions about what I want to do